# Access denied to mysql

Tags: mysql, wamp

On Windows 7, I am trying to use mysql  (installed through WAMP) through the command line without explicitly specifying my username and password, like below

```
shell> mysql
```

To do that, I need to change the configuration file for MySQL, which is supposedly my.ini. I did just that

```
...
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
password    = my_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
...
```

Yet when I try to access mysql, I still get the message

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I fix this?

My my.ini is in

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24
```

Note that the password specified above, my_password, is not my real password and was specified in the file without quotations.

EDIT:

Okay, the above approach works - it allowed me to use mysql through the CLI - but only when I have WAMP on... Why? When it's not on, I get denied access like above...

Comment: Add mysql to Windows PATH.

Comment: Or right click wamp-mysql-mysql console

Comment: I know I can open mysql that way, but I specifically want to open mysql through the windows command line because I will need to do that in a batch script.

Comment: Okay, the above approach works - it allowed me to use mysql through the CLI - but only when I have WAMP on... Why? When it's not on, I get denied access like above...

Comment: Its normal,you start mysql from wamp,install mysql separate as a service if your dont want wamp.

Comment: I believe when WAMP is not on, your MySQL server doesn't work.

Comment: So all access to MySQL server is blocked off if WAMP is not on? Why? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, atleast explain why.

Comment: Check if there are multiple `my.ini` releated with same name or try forcing the `mysqld` service to use a particular `my.ini` using `defaults-file` argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not particularly secure but if you add the account name to the my.ini file as well as the password it will work for you

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
user        = "Fred"
password    = "Bloggs"
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
...
```