# Access denied to MySQL when WAMP is not on

Tags: mysql, wamp

When I try to start MySQL via the commandline

```
shell> mysql
```

when WAMP is not on (not offline, but simply not starting WAMP at all), I am able to access MySQL:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have the user and password set in a my.ini file. It works when I turn WAMP on, but doesn't when I exit WAMP. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

I'm guessing that starting up WAMP somehow grants privelegs to 'root'@'localhost'?

Comment: MySQL is a server (service) that is running in the background.  When WAMP is stopped, that means neither Apache nor MySQL is running.

Comment: I don't understand. I know that without WAMP, neither Apache or Mysql is started. That's why I tried to start it in the commandline. I'm trying to access mysql WITHOUT starting up WAMP.

Comment: The command `mysql` does not start the server.  That command is a client that you can use to access the server.

Comment: you have to install a standalone mysql.

Comment: @Rocket: Thank you, that clears things up immensely!

Comment: @GeorgeNewton:  You need to run `mysqld` to start the server first, before you can access it.  I'd suggest just starting up WAMP, though.

Comment: I could, but the reason I want to start up the server through the commandline is because I am going to make a batch file to execute sql operations on the server on a daily basis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674991/access-denied-to-mysql)

Comment: You have to have the MySQL service running to execute the `mysql` command line processor. So just start the MySQL service using the wampmanager menu. In order to get to a MySQL database the MySQL Service must be running. MySQ is a real DBMS (Database Management System ) not a file access system like Access.